# Loading query results into a Div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a div

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

I then have some jQuery that loads in a page which is query heavy and therefore displays a spinner

```
<script>
$('#page1').click(function () {
// add loading image to div
$('#loading').html('<img src="loading.gif"> loading...');

// run ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "client_reporting_01_data.php",
    success: function (d) {
        // replace div's content with returned data
        $('#loading').html(d);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

My trigger for this is a menu item:

```
<li id="page1" class = "<?php if($current_pgname == "client_reporting_01") echo 'active';         ?>">
<a href="#"> C01: Summary Report</a>
</li>
```

QUESTION:
I have multiple pages and multiple menu items
I'd like to be able to REuse the code I have here to pull the required pages back when the appropriate menu item is clicked.

So I would have another menu item

```
<li id="page2" class = "<?php if($current_pgname == "client_reporting_02") echo 'active';         ?>">
<a href="#"> C02: Summary Report</a>
</li>
```

and another page to call: client_reporting_02

I am just struggling with how to do the jquery to make this work

Somehow the jquery has to be able to read a page requested ie client_reporting_02_data.php

A further complication is how to actually move to that page and have it work. If say I am on pagexyz and i click the menu item for client_reporting_01 - it of course doesn not move there at present as    a href="#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is bind to a `class`, rather than an `id` -

```
<script>
$('.reportLink').click(function () {
...
});
</script>
```

add the class, and a [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attribute that holds the url (ie. `data-url="client_reporting_01_data.php"` and your `li` would now be

```
<li id="page1" class = "reportLink <?php if($current_pgname == "client_reporting_01") echo 'active'; ?>" data-url="client_reporting_01_data.php">
<a href="#"> C01: Summary Report</a>
</li>
```

now your script can be something like -

```
<script>
$('.reportLink').click(function () {
// add loading image to div
$('#loading').html('<img src="loading.gif"> loading...');

linkurl = $(this).data('url');//Probably want to sanitize and/or whitelist to prevent injection

// run ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: linkurl,
    success: function (d) {
        // replace div's content with returned data
        $('#loading').html(d);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply:
It works if i am on the page client_reporting_01_data.php

But if im on a different page and click the menu item it doesnt go to that page.

I havent used this:
      <script>
      $('.reportLink').click(function () {
      ...
      });
      </script>

As I'm not sure where this goes or if it is complete

Comment: `...` is just an abbreviation, so I did not have to copy redundant/unchanged code. It was just to show changing to a class selector. Use the script code at the end of my answer.

Comment: got it - if I'm not on the page already though it doesnt work - i guess its to do with href="#" - clearly click that link isnt quite working

Comment: this so nearly works but not quite - when i am not on the page it will not populate the page

Comment: This works - thanks for the help - my only issue was actually not running it from a single master page - when I have one master page and call in my seperate data pages the above does the job

Answer (score 0):

I am changing your already existing code slightly.  If I understand what you want, the following will work.  Instead of using the ID to call the function, add a generic class to all list items that are effected.  I called it `mypage` here.  Then there are a couple of ways to do it.
One way is:  Instead of storing the url as is as a class, let the id tell you what url you are to look for.  See the changes below for explanation:

```
// Generic class
$('.mypage').click(function () {
// add loading image to div
  $('#loading').html('<img src="loading.gif"> loading...');
// if you need to include the 0 with child page numbers less than 10, you should change your ids accordingly.
  var page=this.id.replace('page',''),
      url= 'client_reporting_' + page + '_data.php';     


// run ajax request
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: url,
    success: function (d) {
       // replace div's content with returned data
       $('#loading').html(d);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delegate an event listener to the `<ul>` elements with an `<a>` anchor and put the url to load in the href? Like so;

### HTML

```
<ul id="pages">
    <li class = "reportLink <?php if($current_pgname == "client_reporting_01") echo 'active'; ?>">
        <a href="client_reporting_01_data.php"> C01: Summary Report</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "reportLink <?php if($current_pgname == "client_reporting_02") echo 'active'; ?>">
        <a href="client_reporting_02_data.php">Another Summary Report</a>
    </li>
</li>
```

### Javascript

```
var $target = $('#loading');

$('#pages').on('click', 'a', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // add loading image to div
    $target.html('<img src="loading.gif"> loading...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: this.href,
        success: function (d) {
            //  replace div's content with returned data
            $target.html(d);
        }
    });

});
```

You could even simplify your code by using `.load` like so:

### Javascript - Simplifed version

```
var $target = $('#loading');

$('#pages').on('click', 'a', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $target
        .html('<img src="loading.gif"> loading...')
        .load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: this seems to jump to client_reporting_01_data.php this is my populating page not my main page

Comment: So what pages should be loaded exactly once you click on the links?

Comment: The prob with the code above is that instead of loading the contents of client_reporting_01_data.php into the <div id="loading"><div> on my main page it simply jumps to the page.
So When I click a link the page doesnt change - it simply inserts into the div the page which contains all my tables (client_reporting_01_data.php)